# How do I find if a specific index exists in a list?

Tags: python

Example:

```lua
List = {"Z" : 0}
```

How would I find the "Z" bit? I'm going to need it inside a for loop

Comment: Your "List" is not a list. It's a dictionary.

Comment: By the way, this is a dictionary, not a list.

Comment: Use the `in` operator: `if 'Z' in List:`

Comment: Your title doesn't match the question text. Do you need to find out *if* `Z` is a key in the list, or do you need to get the *value* of the element with that key?

Comment: But either way, this should be explained in any tutorial on Python dictionaries.

Comment: @Barmar since he cannot differentiate between list and dictionary it would be understandable he cannot ask a proper question

Comment: first do your homework then ask on stack. As everyone mentions its a dict not  list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all that is a dictionary not a list and do not use `list` as a variable name as it is a built-in function name. now to get key of a dictionary value use

```
your_dict_name.items()
```

in a loop it would look like this:

```
for key, value in your_dict.items()
    print(key + ', ' + value)
```

Comment: I'm fairly new to Python. I've never used Python before last week, and someone asked me to make a script to scrape a Jira database.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like to be "this" guy since I'm pretty new in answering on this forum, but check out this to see if it fits your requirements. This site also covers pretty basic Python syntax.

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp

Answering your question. This is a dictionary, not a list. To access a value in a dictionary you have to use square brackets with the key parameter inside them. It kinda looks like accessing a value that is in a list, but actually you're "asking" the dictionary's key to return a value that is contained in it.

For example use:

```
dict_test = {"Z" : 0}
print(dict_test["Z"])
```

To print the value that "Z" key holds.
To iterate through a dictionary that has more than one key, you can use:

```
dict_test = {"X" : 0, "Y": 1, "Z": 2}

for i in dict_test:
    print(dict_test[i])
```

This loop basically inserts every next key from dictionary "dict_test" to variable "i", and then prints next values of this dictionary with key declared as "i" in square brackets next to that dictionary's name.

So if you'd do

```
print(i)
```

inside that for loop, it would tell you which keys are being accessed next every iteration. If you would do

```
print(type(i))
```

it would tell you, that i is a string, which is (as I've mentioned above) being inserted into dictionary to access this certain key's values.

Comment: you could have included info about `.items()` but other than that great explanations, nice job, btw im new to answering questions in this site too

Comment: Thanks @Matiiss! I am treating this as a training for myself too. I also like your explanation, it is short but pretty informative. Hope to see you in further topics :D